# Combine two collection and compare two field values in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to merge the two collection based on comparing two field values

Collection one :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5cd27577732093378c0a760c"),
  "level" : "Safety"
}
```

Collection two :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5c653ffb58ff1515c0a511a5"),
  "course_id" : "1",
  "c_name" : "First Aid",
  "c_level" : "5cd27577732093378c0a760c", 
  "last_update" : "May 14 2019"
}
```

I want to merge the above collection values by comparing the _id of collection one with c_level of collection two

```
  db.one .aggregate([
   {
    $lookup:
   {
   from: "two ",
   localField: "c_level",
   foreignField: "level",
   as: "docs"
   }
   } 
   ])
```

This is showing empty value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got your `localField` and `foreignField` switched (plus a minor change):

```
$lookup:
   {
      from: "two ",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "c_level",
      as: "docs"
   }
```

assuming `c_level` is type `ObjectId`.

Comment: thanks for the update. but the result list all the values but docs is empty  "docs" : [ ]